# Smoothing 3D motion tracking data

Tags: regression, splines, smoothing

I'm working on an application that tracks an object's position in 3D space through time. The hardware generates `(x,y,z,t)` data points, with a non-uniform sampling interval. I want to generate various statistics based on the path itself, as well as it's first and second derivatives (velocity and acceleration).

I tried using centripetal Catmull–Rom splines, but I ran into two problems:

- While cubic splines are smooth, their derivatives are not smooth at the knots
- I realized that I actually wanted smoothing instead of interpolation

So, now I'm trying to figure out how to implement smoothing, using a spline that will have a smooth first and second derivative through knots. I have a few questions:

1. What type of spline can I use that will have a smooth second derivative?
2. Related to #1, how can I select knots? Should the density be based on density of the raw data points (sometimes the update rate drops due to radio interference).
3. Would linear regression be the best choice, or is there something better for tracking motion? (perhaps models inertia?)
4. Do I compute each dimension separately, or is their something to be gained by analyzing the x,y,z together?
5. There are too many data points to process at once, so I need to handle it piecewise. How is this done with regression? Each spline segment needs to lineup with its neighbors. I could add a constraint for the value of the function and it's derivatives at the boundary between chunks, but how would I determine the optimal value?
6. How can I determine the error bound of the position estimate at any given time? If the object is moving slowly, the error bounds of multiple measurements will overlap and allow for a much more accurate position. As the object speeds up, this will degrade back to the error bounds of a single measurement.

I'm quite new to this, and would love any recommendations for readings relating to this problem.

Comment: I welcome any partial answers that only cover some of the questions raised!

Comment: I would recommend splitting your questions up into a few different posts - some are more focused on specific methodological points (questions 1, 2, and 3), and others are much more general theory topics (questions 4, 5, and 6).

Comment: re (1): Cubic splines already have continuous second derivatives everywhere.

Comment: @whuber Yes, but they aren't smooth at the knots. A sharp edge implies infinite "jerk" which is not physically possible.

Comment: It's a smoother, not a physical model!  But if you need greater smoothness, use a higher-degree spline.  Or fit a non-smooth spline and smooth that out: you can make it arbitrarily smooth ($C^\infty$) while changing it inconsequentially.